# How to extend or highlight a horizontal line in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, line

I'd like to create kind of a baseline in my chart, where there a multiple columns, and a horizontal line of value "1", which starts at the y-axis and goes beyond the last column. See this example:

[image]

Now, I have created something similar, but it's not yet succeeded:

[image]

The series code is simple:

```
            series:
            [{
                type: 'column',
                data: [4.05,2.81,2.1,1.20,0.37]
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Globale Biokapazität',
                data: [1,1,1,1,1]
            }]
```

Is there any parameter I can set to extend the line? Or is there any other way to highlight a line?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Could you add your codes in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are a lot of example about [plotLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines)

Just use something like this:

```
yAxis: {
    plotLines:[{
        value:450,
        color: '#ff0000',
        width:2,
        zIndex:4,
        label:{text:'goal'}
    }]
},
```

one of them: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/4R5HH/4/)

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

- use plotLine instead: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines
- change data format, with fixed min and max:

  ```
       xAxis: {
           min: 0,
           max: 5
       },
       series:
      [{
          type: 'column',
          data: [4.05,2.81,2.1,1.20,0.37]
      },
      {
          type: 'line',
          name: 'Globale Biokapazität',
          data: [[-0.5, 1] , [5.5, 1]]
      }]
  ```